# What is the type of my kernel, 32 bits or 64 bits?

Tags: kernel

Four commands on my pc:

```
$ dpkg -l |grep linux-image
```

Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on **32 bit x86** SMP

It means my Ubuntu kernel is 32 bits?

```
$ uname -a
Linux ny 3.4.0-030400-generic #201205210521 SMP Mon May 21 09:22:02 UTC 2012 **x86_64 x86_64 x86_64** GNU/Linux
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, **x86-64**, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x37cdd635587f519989044055623abff939002027, stripped
$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, **x86-64**, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x7aa29ded613e503fb09fb75d94026f3256f01e7a, stripped
```

up 3 commands mean my kernel is 64 bits?

My question: What is my kernel, 32 bits or 64 bits? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the programs installed are on their 64-bit version, so I assume it's a 64-bit system.

Comment: This is not always true; on PPC64 it is possible to have a 32-bit kernelspace and a 64-bit userspace.

Answer (score 0):

`file` only tells you the architecture of binaries. There are cases where a kernel has or uses a different "bitness" userspace (SPARCv9, ARM Thumb), so this cannot be considered accurate.

Only `uname` gives you direct information about the currently running kernel, therefore you are running a 64-bit kernel.

Comment: $ dpkg -l |grep linux-image  ---->

Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP-----what does it mean? Thank you!

Comment: And? The package manager doesn't run the system.

Comment: sorry? what do you mean?

Comment: `uname -m`; i386 = 32bit and x86_64 = 64bit; another command is `dpkg --print-architecture`

Comment: uname -m show the hardware architecture----
Would tell me why the following command output is x86 for my PC? Thank you.----

$ dpkg -l |grep linux-image------

Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP